# Modifying an individual subsection number

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have an article divided into sections and subsections. I need to insert a subsection "5.2a" between "5.2" and "5.3". What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Hi, you can find the answer to your question in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839647/latex-how-to-change-one-of-section-numbers-to-a-custom-letter. Only small adaptation would be required to get the result you want.

Comment: I removed the [tag:sections-paragraphs] tag because your question could also be useful for modifying chapter numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is just for just one time, the easies way would be to redefine the representation for the subsection counter, and then revert to the original definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}a}
\subsection{Test Subsection One A}\label{sec:test}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: instead of re-resetting after the changed `subsection`, one could precede the initial `\addtocounter` by `\begingroup` and replace the second `\renewcommand\thesubsection` by `\endgroup`.  the changed heading *will* go into the table of contents.  (and yes, i know these are "plain" tex commands, not latex, but they're more visible than braces, which could also be used.)

Comment: Thanks, as this is a one-off I think I'll go for the quick and dirty solution!

Answer (score 5):

A more general solution is to do the redefinition without any assumption about what `\thesubsection` expands to.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % uncomment for testing with it

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialsubsection}[1]{%
  \def\@specialsubsectionsuffix{#1}%
  \@dblarg\@specialsubsection
}
\def\@specialsubsection[#1]#2{%
 \begingroup
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\thesubsection\expandafter{%
   \thesubsection\@specialsubsectionsuffix}%
 \@ifundefined{theHsubsection}%
   {}%
   {\expandafter\def\expandafter\theHsubsection\expandafter{%
      \theHsubsection\@specialsubsectionsuffix}}%
 \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}%
 \subsection[#1]{#2}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}

\specialsubsection{a}{Test Subsection One A}\label{sec:test}

\specialsubsection{b}[For toc]{Test Subsection One B}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two}

\end{document}
```

This allows also for a different TOC entry, with the usual optional argument (after the suffix).

The `\theHsubsection` bit is to make the code work with `hyperref`.

[image]

Comment: Looks excellent, but it doesn't appear to work nicely with `\ref`.